# Web Service as400 - Error Favicon

Tags: webservice, as400

Estoy levantando un web Service en as400, pero me arroja los siguientes errores:

> El archivo /www/WebService/htdocs/favicon.ico no existe
>   El URI de la petición GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0 no es válido

El servicio es un programa RPG. El programa funciona bien.
De hecho, se encuentra corriendo en otra máquina y las configuraciones se realizaron de igual forma.

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http[s]://[midominio]/favicon.ico` es una URL especial. Se utiliza para dejar un pequeño fichero gráfico, que el navegador puede usar para representar el sitio web, por ejemplo al lado del título de la página web o en los favoritos.

[image: Ejemplos de favicon]

Lo que tu ves son logs de peticiones de ese archivo que tu servidor rechaza porque no dispone de ese recurso. Probablemente las peticiones sean de algún acceso via navegador al webservice (quizás para comprobar el WSDL).

No tiene mayor importancia